# issue in extarct .gz file in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, tar

I am trying to extract tar.gz file in Ubuntu original file size of tar.gz is 760mb but after extract the file it shows 260mb.I am confused because original file  size is 1.5 gb after convert the original file into tar.gz size was 760mb but extract the tar.gz file it shows 260mb only instead of 1.5gb what can i do.can any one help me to find the solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you creating that tar.gz and extracting it?

Comment: @ÖzgürEroğlu i received tar.gz file with 1.5 gb content and tar.gz file size is 760 mb. i am extracting using terminal and right click event in ubuntu system

Comment: after receiving, did you check its md5 chekcsum? It is a big zip file and you should be sure that it was downloaded without any error. Did you used these commands gunzip file.tar.gz then tar -xvf file.tar

Comment: @ÖzgürEroğlu i tried this but it also same